# CommandObject not working in grails

Tags: validation, grails

I am working on Grails sample application. I had a controller and a command object for validating request params as below.

```
package com.samples

class UserController {

    def index() { redirect action:getUser }

    def getUser(UserCommand userCommand) {
        if(userCommand.hasErrors()){
            if(userCommand.errors.hasFieldErrors("login")) {
                render "provide valid login"
            } else if(userCommand.errors.hasFieldErrors("password")) {
                 render "provide valid password"
            }

        } else {
            render "The user login and password is valid"
        }
    }
}

class UserCommand {
    String login
    String password 

    static constraints = {
        login(blank: false)
        password(blank: false)
    }

}
```

When I run the Grails app and browse, I get the following error:

```
URI
    /Library/user/getUser
Class
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
Message
    com.samples.UserCommand.getLogin()Ljava/lang/Object;
```

The error shows that it is looking for `getLogin()` method but I think get/set methods will be dynamically generated by Grails.

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace?

Comment: use @Validateable above UserCommand class. It should work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i include the UserCommand class inside the UserController class(instead of writing as a seperate classes in same file), then it is working fine.

Thanks for all your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the UserCommand class inside grails-app/domain package.I think it is outside the domain package and grails not able to generate the getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the

```
def index() { redirect action: getUser }
```

needing to be changed to

```
def index() { redirect action: "getUser" }
```

it appears your code is working correctly.

#### For Command Objects in General:

If you include the command object in the controller it is already "validateable".  Also, do not put it in domain class, unless you want to persist the data.  If you want to keep the command object outside of the controller, put it in src/groovy, in which case you would need to mark it as `@grails.validation.Validateable`.

As for your code, put your error messages in your command object, not the controller action, so you check them in one place and then return the command object with errors back to the view to display the errors.

```
package com.samples

class UserController {

    def index() { redirect action: "getUser" }

    def getUser(UserCommand userCommand) {
        if(userCommand.hasErrors()){
            return [userCommand: userCommand]  //if you are returning to the getUser view
        } else {
            render "The user login and password are correct"
        }
    }
}

class UserCommand {
    String login
    String password 

    static constraints = {
        login(blank: false)
        password(blank: false)
    }

}
```

See the Grails documentation for more information: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code, it should work fine. Please check if

- The source files are groovy by extension.
- You have the source files in correct package and folder.
- Do a grails clean.

I guess you are just trying out with the Grails framework, but do look for better ways to do stuff in Grails.